# RowGroupingModule and content in first column

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In ag-Grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/) I have column definitions like that:

```
   columnDefs: [
            {
                colId: 'tasks',
                field: 'tasks',
                rowGroup: true,
                hide: true
            },
            {
                colId: 'person',
                field: 'person',
                width: 500,
                cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'center' },
                cellRenderer: (params) => {
                    if (!params.node.group) {
                        return `
                            ${params.data.person.name} - ${params.data.person.job}
                        `;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            },
            {
                colId: 'total',
                field: 'total',
                width: 100,
                aggFunc: 'sum'
            }
   ]
```

First column aggregates by task property in data object, but each row of grouped data starts with empty column. What I would like to have is the content of second column in the first (actually definition for the person should be removed and `${params.data.person.name} - ${params.data.person.job}` should be placed as content under details of `colId: 'tasks'`).

I have tried to achieve it with `cellRenderer` for tasks, but it allowed me to change only grouped row not the details underneath of it.

[Image for better explanation of desired solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiS9o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your case is similar to example here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-provided-renderer-group/

You need to provide innerRenderer, so you can provide any content you want inside of grid's grouping cell.